# Can't bind JSON data with map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I have this JSON below for example and I need to get the `name` of `genres`.

```
{
  "adult": false,
  "backdrop_path": "/5qxePyMYDisLe8rJiBYX8HKEyv2.jpg",
  "budget": 178000000,
  "genres": [
    {
      "id": 12,
      "name": "Adventure"
    },
    {
      "id": 28,
      "name": "Action"
    },
    {
      "id": 53,
      "name": "Thriller"
    }
  ],
  "homepage": null
}
```

But when I use the map function the React return a error:

> TypeError: this.state.persons.map is not a function

```
class Content extends React.Component {
    state = {
        persons: []
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get(Config.apiUrl + 353081 + Config.apiKey)
            .then(res => {
                const persons = res.data;
                this.setState({ persons });
            })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={9}>
                        <Typography gutterBottom={true}><b>Budget:</b> { this.state.persons.budget }</Typography>
                        <Typography gutterBottom={true}><b>Genres:</b> { this.state.persons.map(person => <li key={person.genres.id}>{person.genres.name}</li>) }</Typography>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it should be `this.setState({ persons: res.data });` and not just `this.setState({ persons: res });`? You can `console.log` the `res` in the axios callback and see if it contains the data you think.

Comment: `res.data` is an array ? I don't think so, as per the exception you mentioned.

Comment: @Tholle Yes, the res data contains what I need.

Comment: what is contains.. can you do console.log and show?

Comment: If `res.data` looks like the object in your first code snippet, it will give you the error, since regular objects don't have a `map` method.

Comment: @ArupRakshit yes, is an array. I'm just need to get the name of genres, but I think the map function is not correctly

Comment: Give a screenshot of the console.log output

Comment: @ArupRakshit https://postimg.cc/image/kzajp77r1/

Comment: @GojiBerry Yes as I said, it is an `{}` construct, not `[]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you state should be an object literal `{}`, not `[]`. Also `res.data` returns an `{..}`, not `[]`. If it returns an array, then `this.state.persons.budget` should throw error, but it doesn't. That proves, `persons` state is not an array.

```
state = {
  persons: {
    genres: []
  }
}
```

And then

```
<Typography gutterBottom={true}>
  <b>Genres:</b>{" "}
  {this.state.persons.genres.map(genre => <li key={genre.id}>{genre.name}</li>)}
</Typography>;
```

Comment: `this.state.persons.genres` will be `undefined` initially, so `this.state.persons.genres.map` will give you an error.

Comment: Yes that is true also.

Comment: It works, thank you all. So I need to "say" at `persons` constructor what array I need get from the `res`?